# Python - micro-web frameworks -

Tags: python

There is a lot going on in web frameworks - they can take an age to learn.

So, what is it I am missing when I say that WSGI defines pretty much all we need to respond to a request.  If I overload the environ dict I can store almost all I need, so what am I gaining from a framework?

Comment: I suggest actually learning what WSGI does and what an arbitrarily chosen framework does. (The latter being a strict superset of the former.) Generally speaking, if nothing else, frameworks enforce a set of conventions on structuring your application at a macro level, and provide a bunch of shortcuts on connecting components in this structure that are related by this convention. (The canonical example would be a controller and the view that's rendered with its results.)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write a web application using only WSGI, but at some point you're going to have to solve the following problems:

- How do I handle different url requests?
- How do I parse form data?
- How do I render a response?
- How do I support sessions?
- How do I persist data?
- etc, etc, etc...

Each web framework solves some (or all) of these problems.  Yes, you could design and implement solutions yourself, but web frameworks contain solutions that other people have found work very well for them.  So that's what you get from a framework: a bunch of suggestions for how to solve common problems when writing web apps.

Finally, it's easy to be overwhelmed by the number of choices for web frameworks, but if you just learn one, others will be much easier to understand.  I would recommend learning either django or a more minimalist framework like flask.  Other frameworks are pretty similar to these two, and you'll be able to pick them up easily.